# How to check what id is hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have ids on page like:

```
<div id="1"><div id="inner-1" style="display:none;"></div></div>
<div id="2"><div id="inner-2" style="display:none;"></div></div>
<div id="3"><div id="inner-3" style="display:none;"></div></div>
```

Then, i have js to toggle visibility on hover parent id:

```
var toggleAuthor = function(id) {
    jQuery('#inner-'+id).fadeIn();
};

var toggleAuthorOff = function(id) {
    jQuery('#inner-'+id).delay(1000).fadeOut();
};
```

So the problem is how to send hovering id there, i think i must assigh hovering id to var and send it, something like that:

```
var aid = 38;
jQuery(aid).hover(function() {
    toggleAuthor(aid);
}, function() {
    toggleAuthorOff(aid);
});
```

But how to get only hovering id?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*I have js toggle visibility on hover parent id*" you say that but your code appears to toggle the child divs.

Comment: Sorry, bad english! Hovering parent, toggling child i mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a class to all of them, say "tester":

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="1" class="tester"><div id="inner-1" style="display:none;"></div></div>
    <div id="2" class="tester"><div id="inner-2" style="display:none;"></div></div>
    <div id="3" class="tester"><div id="inner-3" style="display:none;"></div></div>
</div>
```

Then use the following jQuery:

```
$('#container').on('mouseenter','.tester',function() {
    toggleAuthor(this.id);
}).on('mouseleave','.tester',function(){
    toggleAuthorOff(this.id);
});
```

Here's a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Y8JB/)

Comment: That's very simple and perfect! Thank you very much.

Comment: This would fade the outer divs though, the OP appears to want to fade the inner divs.

Comment: @YotamOmer yeah silly mistake...of course if you fade the parent the inner children will go with out with it, d'oh. +1

Comment: Hm, for some reason it's not working when the second page of divs loading with ajax.

Comment: Yep, you will have to use `.live()` or `.on()` on the parent element for it to apply to newly generated content. will edit in a second

Comment: Oh, i understand. My code didn't see new DOM elements, thanks!

Comment: Updated! check the new version

Comment: Got error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'  (anonymous function)

Must be #container first parent of divs?

Comment: `.on()` was intoduced on jQuery 1.7. if you are using a version prior to that use `.live()`

Comment: If you're using < 1.7 use [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (even the docs for [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) recommend *not* using it). And `$(this).attr('id')`, I'd strongly suggest changing to `this.id` (it's universal, faster and cheaper than invoking jQuery every time).

Comment: Thanks for recommendations :)

Comment: [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Y8JB/8/). note that delegate using other order of arguments. [read docs](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: Yes, now it's perfect. But i can't answer to my question. I am a new one, so i need wait 8 hours to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

you can also work with css-classes instead of IDs:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="1" class="outer"><div id="inner-1" class="inner"></div></div>
    <div id="2" class="outer"><div id="inner-2" class="inner"></div></div>
    <div id="3" class="outer"><div id="inner-3" class="inner"></div></div>
</div>
```

with the css def:

```
.inner { display: none; }
```

and the js:

```
$(".outer").mouseenter ( function () { $(this).find(".inner").fadeIn();});
$(".outer").mouseleave ( function () { $(this).find(".inner").delay(1000).fadeOut();});
```

Comment: yes, it will toggle any item that has the class "inner" and resides inside an item with a class "outer", regardless of IDs (in fact, you don't need to have IDs for this to work)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this:

```
<div class="check" id="1">1<div id="inner-1" style="display:none;"></div></div>
<div class="check"  id="2">2<div id="inner-2" style="display:none;"></div></div>
<div class="check" id="3">3<div id="inner-3" style="display:none;"></div></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function()
  {
         $(".check").mouseenter ( function (e) { alert(e.currentTarget.id) });
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xvZmR/5/)